# matrix multiplication in python - problem with creating result

Tags: python, loops, math

Hey I need to multiply two matrix

I am refering to this code which isnt mine, but I want to understand:

```
# Program to multiply two matrices using nested loops

# 3x3 matrix
X = [[12,7,3],
    [4 ,5,6],
    [7 ,8,9]]
# 3x4 matrix
Y = [[5,8,1,2],
    [6,7,3,0],
    [4,5,9,1]]
# result is 3x4
x = len(X)
y = len(Y[0])
result = []
resultx = []
for each in range(1,y+1):
    resultx.append(0)
for each in range(1,x+1):
    result.append(resultx)

# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
# iterate through columns of Y
    for j in range(len(Y[0])):
        # iterate through rows of Y
        for k in range(len(Y)):
            result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]

for r in result:
    print(r)
```

The author from the code is creating the result in code like this:

```
result = [[0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0],
     [0,0,0,0]]
```

I tried to create it with two for loops:

```
x = len(X)
y = len(Y[0])
result = []
resultx = []
for each in range(1,y+1):
    resultx.append(0)
for each in range(1,x+1):
    result.append(resultx)
```

The Output is the same, even the type(result) is the same.
But the final solution is different.
So my Question is why my final result is

```
[307, 414, 245, 64],[307, 414, 245, 64],[307, 414, 245, 64]
```

and the correct solution is:

```
[114, 160, 60, 27],[74, 97, 73, 14,[119, 157, 112, 23]
```

I realized that 114 + 74 + 119 is equal to 307.

My question:
Why does it matter how I am creating the result matrix or what am I doing wrong?
EDIT:
To clarify the problem:

```
result = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

the final solution is: `[114, 160, 60, 27],[74, 97, 73, 14,[119, 157, 112, 23]`

When I try to create the 0-Matrix: instead of hardcoding it:

```
x = len(X)
y = len(Y[0])
result = []
resultx = []
for each in range(1,y+1):
    resultx.append(0)
for each in range(1,x+1):
    result.append(resultx)
```

the solution is: `[307, 414, 245, 64],[307, 414, 245, 64],[307, 414, 245, 64]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your code when you are trying to create the 0-Matrix in this for loop:

```
for each in range(1,x+1):
    result.append(resultx)
```

you are appending an object called "resultx" 3 times to another object called "result" but this is one single object in the memory so basically you have 3 of the same rows. For instance when you are manipulating result[0][0] actually you are also manipulating result[0][1] and result[0][2].  You should change your code like this so each time you make a new object with the same name "resultx":

```
result = []
for each in range(1,x+1):
    resultx = []
    for each in range(1,y+1):
        resultx.append(0)
    result.append(resultx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice try!!!
but if you wanted to multiply two matrices you need to travel row wise and column wise for each index(mat1=m, n and mat2=n, x then resultant will m, x) so it requires three loop explained below.

1. to travel for m, x(resultant matrices).
2. to travel for row multiplications.
3. to travel for column multiplications.

another solution

```
result = np.dot(A,B)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but my challenge is to create it without numpy.
But, my question is still the same, why does it matter how I am creating the reuslt [[0,0,0,,,]] matrix.

Comment: The multiplication isnt the problem (yet), I am wondering, why the final solution with hardcoded result = [[0,0,0,0] etc] is correct, and mine is not when I try to create the 0 - Matrix

Comment: See the EDIT please